# How to prove: $\:a\:<x<b$ while $0<\lambda <1,\:a\:<\:x_1<b,a<x_2<b,\:x=\lambda x_1+\left(1-\lambda \right)x_2$

Tags: calculus

if

> $0<\lambda <1$ and $\:a\:<\:x_1<b,a<x_2<b$ and $ \:x=\lambda x_1+\left(1-\lambda \right)x_2$

how to prove :

> $\:a\:<x<b$

Comment: Where is the point between $x_1$ and $x_2$ that separates the length in ratio $\lambda : 1-\lambda$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that

$$ x < \lambda b + (1-\lambda) b = b $$

and

$$ x > a(1-\lambda) + a \lambda = a $$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the inequalities through by $\lambda$ and ($1-\lambda)$ respectively (both are $\gt 0$):

$$\lambda a\lt \lambda x_1 \lt \lambda b$$

$$(1-\lambda) a\lt (1-\lambda) x_2 \lt (1-\lambda) b$$

Then add them together:

$$\lambda a+(1-\lambda) a\lt \lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2 \lt \lambda b+(1-\lambda) b$$

($x\lt a, y\lt b \implies x+y\lt a+y\lt a+b$)

And simplify:

$$a\lt x \lt b$$

Answer (score 0):

Any point $x$ which lies between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is of the form $x= \lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2$. (where $\lambda$ lies between $0$ and $1$). Also x divides $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the ratio $\lambda:(1-\lambda)$.

Coming back to your question, as $x_1$ and $x_2$ lies between $a$ and $b$, $x= \lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2$ also lies between $a$ and $b$.